# Merging of audio and video in iPhone device is not working. In simulator merging of audio and video is taking time in AVAssestTrack initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:URL, audioUrl:URL) -> AVMutableComposition {

        let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
        let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

        mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)
        mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)

        let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
        let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]

        do{
            try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)


            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aAudioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        }catch{

        }

        totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

        let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
        mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

        mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280,height: 720)

        return mixComposition
}
```

`let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]` **it says array is empty**

Answer (score 0):

Completion is not required as given below. I needed the the completion code.

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:URL, audioUrl:URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> (Void))
    {
        let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()


        //start merge
        let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
        let tracksKey = "tracks"
        aVideoAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [tracksKey], completionHandler: {
            let status = aVideoAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: tracksKey, error: nil)
            if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {
//                let audioTracks : Array<AVAssetTrack> = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)
                
                let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)
                aAudioAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: [tracksKey], completionHandler: {
                    let status1 = aAudioAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: tracksKey, error: nil)
                    if status1 == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {
                        
                        mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)
                        mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!)
                                                
                        let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
                        let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]
                        
                        do{
                            try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
                            
                            //In my case my audio file is longer then video file so i took videoAsset duration
                            //instead of audioAsset duration
                            
                            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aAudioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
                            
                            //Use this instead above line if your audiofile and video file's playing durations are same
                            
                            //            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aAudioAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
                            
                        }catch{
                            
                        }
                        
                        totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )
                        
                        let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
                        mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
                        
                        mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280,height: 720)
                        
                        //        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
                        //        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
                        //
                        //
                        //        AVPlayerVC.player = player
                        self.mixComposition = mixComposition // You can use mix composition to play. Ex : self.playerViewController.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: AVPlayerItem.init(asset: self.mixComposition!, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: nil))
                        _ = completion(true)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```